# routing traffic through tor and socks5, different to socks5 and then tor?

Tags: networking, proxy, tor, socks, socks5

I'd like to route traffic through tor and a socks5 proxy.

Question: Is there a difference between routing:

- laptop -> tor -> socks55
- laptop -> socks5 -> tor

Comment: How would you achieve the first path? What’s “socks5” in this context? Some third-party service? A program on your laptop? A program on a dedicated machine you control? And what’s your ultimate goal? To hide yourself from “socks5”? Or to hide “socks5” from the internet?

Comment: socks5 proxy   ...

Comment: Of course it is. That doesn’t help at all, though. Please try and answer all the questions in my comment.